# Why is setting the UUID on a checksummed filesystem so slow, and should I be worried?

Tags: filesystem, uuid

I cloned a drive, and now I am trying to change the UUID of the cloned drive.  There are various answers on AskUbuntu as to how to do this.  I was prompted to run a fresh e2fsck first, which I did.  But when I actually ran tune2fs I got this message unexpectedly:

```
Setting UUID on a checksummed filesystem could take some time.
Proceed anyway (or wait 5 seconds to proceed) ? (y,N)
```

While I was trying to process what this meant to decide what to do, it went ahead and started.  It took a few minutes to complete, but now I am concerned.  What is the explanation of why it takes so long?  Is this something I should be worried about?

Comment: I think the checksum of the filesystem has to be updated and that takes time depending on the size of the filesystem.

Comment: Sadly, somebody broke interface of tune2fs by making this stupid question and by ignoring -f option.